# HOWTO: disable touchpad with key sequence

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, and would like to know how to enable/disable "tapping" mouse clicks. When I have my mouse plugged in, this feature is pain in the *ss, but when mouse isn't here, I really need it since my left mouse button on touchpad is broken.

To make it quick:

Q: How to set key sequence to toggle mouse left click by tapping?

Thanks

Comment: Computer configuration questions belong on superuser, voting to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom keyboard shortcut that runs `gconftool-2 --toggle /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/tap_to_click`.